# How Can I use .NET Framework 4.8 on an WPF Class Library?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

So I want to create an WPF Class Library but in the .NET Framework 4.8.
But in the creating I only get this two Frameworks to choose:

[image: Version]

How Can I get .NET Framework 4.8 in this to Choose?
Because when I just use the normal Class Library, without the WPF in the name I can only add an UserControl. I cant choose in that something like Ressource dictionary for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose

**WPF User Control Library (.NET Framework)**

or

**WPF Custom Control Library (.NET Framework)**

instead of

**WPF Class Library**

as project template.

---

Alternatively, replace

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

with

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in the project file (.csproj).

---

You can also support multiple target frameworks like this:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;net48</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Where did I get WPF User Control Library ? Because I dont have this names on the list. And the TargetFramework, in which File did I find this?

Comment: TargetFramework is in the .csproj file. Double click on the project in Visual Studio. For the project templates, the appropriate Workloads must be installed in Visual Studio Installer.